# Unix command to cut file and recreate new one

Tags: unix, awk, cut

I have a `input.txt` which contains data like this

```
123

1234

1223
```

I want it to convert to another file `output.txt` and file should look like this

```
'123','1234','1223'
```

Can you someone please let me how it can be done in unix?

Comment: Is there REALLY a blank line between each line of data in your input?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
tr -s '\n' < input.txt | sed "s/.*/'&'/g" | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//g' > output.txt
```

Comment: thanks alot brother....... "sat" you the man

Comment: The last sed can just be 's/,$//'

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed`

```
cat input.txt | sed -n "s!\(.*\)!'\1'!;H;\$!b;x;s!^\n!!;s!\n!,!g;p"
```

Read each line in (not printing by default `-p`), and then append it to the hold space `H` - then stop for all lines except the last one `\$b`.
On the last line - copy the hold space into the pattern space `x`, ditch the first newline (the hold space has a newline in it to start with), and then replace the remaining newlines with ','. Finally print out the pattern space `p`.

You could use a perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @lines = <>;
chomp(@lines);
print join(',', map { "\"$_\"" } @lines), "\n";

./script input.txt
```

Comment: Thanks alot Beano:) ... but  i am looking for commands in unix only

Comment: Updated answer to give a sed alternative

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't you with bash. Try this in Python:

```
InputFilepath = /path/to/input.txt
OutputFilepath = /path/to/output.txt

with open(InputFilepath, "r") as f:
    words = f.read().splitlines() #may be not needed?
    result = ','.join(f)

with open(OutputFilepath, "w") as g:
    g.write(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet there is a cleaner way to do this but can't think of it so far.

```
#         1            2                          3             4
sed "/^[ \t]*$/d; s/\(.*\)/'\1'/" input.txt | tr "\n" "," | sed 's/,$//'
```

1. remove blanks lines (including lines containing spaces/tabs).
2. add single quotes around each line
3. replace new-line with comma
4. remove trailing ,

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` version

```
awk 'NF{s=s q$0q","} END {sub(/,$/,x,s);print s}' q="'" file
'123','1234','1223'
```

How it works:

```
awk '
NF {                # When line is not blank, do:
    s=s q$0q","}    # Chain together all data with ' before and ',
END {               # End block
    sub(/,$/,x,s)   # Remove last ,
    print s}        # Print the result
    ' q="'" file    # Helps awk to handle single quote in print, and read the file
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for a multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n+$' -v FS='\n+' -v OFS="','" -v q="'" '{$1=$1; print q $0 q }' file
'123','1234','1223'
```

It just reads the whole file as one record (`RS='\n+$'`) using sequences of contiguous newlines as the input field separator (`FS='\n+'`) then recompiles the record using `','` as the output field separator (`OFS="','"`) by assigning a field to itself (`$1=$1`), and prints the result with a `'` at the front and back.